# Matrix and Vector Norm with diagonal matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I don't even know where to begin with a problem like this. Where should I start? A thorough 
(no shortcuts )answer and explanation is greatly appreciated.

Let A be symmetric positive definite. Show that the so-called energy norm

$$||x||_A = \sqrt{x^TAx}$$

is indeed a (vector) norm. [Hint: show first that it suffices to consider only diagonal matrices A with positive entries on the main diagonal]

Comment: Start by making a list of properties to be proved. Then prove them in the case of diagonal $A$. Then think about diagonalizing matrices.

Comment: start with a known 2 by 2 symmetric positive definite matrix and see how that goes.

Comment: If you consider the fact that all scalar products induce a norm you can easily prove this by proving that x^TAx  = <x, Ax> is indeed a scalar product. This can be done by proving that <x, Ax> follows linearity, symmetry and positive definiteness of scalar products.